# Unexpected behavior when handling lost connections to Redis via connect-redis and express-session

Tags: node.js, express, redis, express-session

I have an express app that uses `express-session` and `connect-redis` to set up a Redis session store. After following both the connect-redis docs [section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis#how-do-i-handle-lost-connections-to-redis) on "How do I handle lost connections to Redis?" and also its reference to this [post](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/99), I integrated the below function:

```
var sessionMiddleware = session( /* setup session here */ )

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var tries = 10

  function lookupSession(error) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    }

    tries -= 1
    console.log(`Num tries left: ${attempts}`);
    console.log(req.session);

    if (req.session !== undefined) {
      return next()
    }

    if (tries < 0) {
      return next(new Error('oh no'))
    }

    sessionMiddleware(req, res, lookupSession)
  }

  lookupSession()
})
```

I'm confused because each time I make a request or refresh my app it the `lookupSession` function is called **twice** - where `req.session` is always undefined the first time and then defined by the second time. Additionally, it doesn't seem to matter if my Redis instance is actually up or not.

Sometimes a single refresh causes the `lookupSession` function to get called 5+ times just printing out the same message block again and again:

```
Num tries left: 9
undefined
Num tries left: 8
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: ...,
    _expires: ..,
    originalMaxAge: ...,
    httpOnly: ...,
    sameSite: ...,
    secure: ...
  }
}
```

Any idea why the `req.session` is always initially undefined and then defined (in two back-to-back calls)? I would imagine that the session shouldn't be able to be defined as long as the Redis instance is still down and I'd imagine that it should defined when it is. And any idea why this function may be triggered 5+ times printing the same `tries` count out without actually decrementing it each time down to 0?

Comment: Are you actually getting lost connections that you need to handle? The redis library will attempt to reconnect automatically if it goes down and if you're connecting locally that should basically never happen. I'd argue you're making this far too complex and can just use the method here https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis#how-do-i-handle-lost-connections-to-redis

Comment: @JasonRoman It's okay if a connection is lost - the main goal is to make sure that the `req.session` is defined after the redis client reconnects again. It looks like I don't really understand how  that `lookupSession` function is working. Are you saying that with the base function in the link you provided would be enough to create a new `req.session` when redis does come back up? Wouldn't I need to prevent propagating the `return next(new Error('oh no'))` as well? Thanks

Comment: `lookupSession` is just re-sending your request through your session middleware a few times until it hopefully generates a session for the request; my argument is it's probably rare enough that you can just throw an error to the client and make them retry the request since redis is already attempting to reconnect automatically, and if it can't do it in time then your retry logic probably isn't going to work either

Comment: @jasonRoman Oh, so if I don't re-send the request using the `lookupSession` and just throw an error this won't prevent `req.session` from coming back and the user shouldn't have a problem once redis is connected again? It's perfectly fine to drop a request every once in a while with my use case. I had thought that the session would be broken if you didn't use lookupSession (at least until you bounced the whole service)

Comment: @jasonRoman also what's stopping the lookupSession from just re-sending the request through 10 consecutive times before redis is back up? does it wait for the redis client `retry_strategy`?

Comment: To your first question, it shouldn't prevent it from coming back; to your second, nothing is stopping it. This might be a good time to test on your own; manually shut off your Redis server and try a request; then turn the server back on and try another request after it, and see what happens.